# ¿Como utilizar el editcolum para cambiar el numero (id) de una columna por datos (nombre) de otra (relationship)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy realizando un proyecto con laravel pero soy nuevo, por lo que validando encontre una forma interesante de definir los datos y tablas que se van a mostrar en el index sin tener que definirlos en por cada carpeta, por lo que mi pregunta es:

¿Como puedo modificar el numero de categoria que me muestra en la tabla (imagen de abajo), para que me aparezca el nombre al que pertenece ese numero?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente tome un proyecto interésate que estaba publicado en git, para tomarlo de referencia y me fije que utiliza el editcolumn para realizar ese mismo proceso que estoy preguntando, por lo que me interese en como lo hacía e intente replicarlo, pero sin éxito.

Aquí está mi modelo de computador

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Computadores extends Model
{
    use HasRoles;
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'computadores';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
        'codigo',
        'imagen',
        'descripcion',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    //Relacionamos con la tabla pivot de categorias para los usuarios y sus categorias.....
    public function categoriainv(){
        return $this->hasOne(Categoriainv::class);
    }
    public function users(){
        
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
```

PD: aquí también intento crear una relationship con categoriainv

Aquí esta mi modelo de Categoriainv

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categoriainv extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'categoriainv';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
        'descripcion',
    ];
```

Aquí esta mi controlador

```
class ComputadoresController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $columns = array(
            array('data'=>'id'),
            array('data'=>'nombre'),
            array('data'=>'idcategoria'),
            array('data'=>'codigo'),
            array('data'=>'idusuario'),
            array('data'=>'imagen'),
            array('data'=>'descripcion'),
            array('data'=>'action'),
        );
        $head = array(
            'ID',
            'Nombre',
            'Categoria',
            'Codigo',
            'Usuario',
            'Imagen',
            'Descipción',
            'Action',
        );
        return view('computadores.index',[
            'columns'=>$columns,
            'head'=>$head ,
            'status'=>Estatu::all(),
            'usuarios'=>User::all(),
            'permission'=>Permission::all(),
            'categoriainv'=>Categoriainv::all()
        ]);
    }


    public function datatables(){
        $table = Datatables::of(Computadores::all());
        $table->addColumn('action', function($row){
            $url = url('computadores').'/'.$row['id'];
            return view('layouts.buttons_datatables',['id'=>$row['id'],'url'=>$url]);
        })->editColumn('idcategoria', function($row){;
             return $row->categoriainv->nombre;
        })->rawColumns(['action']);
        return $table->make(true);
        
    }
```

Aqui donde aplico mi edit para idcategoria

```
    public function datatables(){
        $table = Datatables::of(Computadores::all());
        $table->addColumn('action', function($row){
            $url = url('computadores').'/'.$row['id'];
            return view('layouts.buttons_datatables',['id'=>$row['id'],'url'=>$url]);
        })->editColumn('idcategoria', function($row){;
             return $row->categoriainv->name;
        })->rawColumns(['action']);
        return $table->make(true);
        
    }
```

donde despues de casi 2 dias logre que me apareciera este error:

```
"error": "Exception Message:\n\nSQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categoriainv.computadores_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categoriainv` where `categoriainv`.`computadores_id` = 6 and `categoriainv`.`computadores_id` is not null limit 1)"
```

}

donde ya tuve un avance o eso quiero creer ya que me aparece que no reconoce la columna, mas ya esta realizando el intento de realizar la traduccion que requiero.

Aquí esta mi index donde se trae todos los datos y los publica

```
<table-vue :columns="{{ json_encode($columns) }}" :head="{{ json_encode($head) }}" ></table-vue>
```

PD: ya se mas o menos como funcionan los relationship y los add y edit en laravel, más sin embargo nunca he visto a estos dos unidos o en tutoriales solo el basico de como utilizarlos y un poco mas engorroso ya que hay que definirlos en el index y otros lados, solo he encontrado por esta página como utilizarlos y los he encontrado solo en esta página, de los cuales me resolvieron mi duda y pude sacar por fin ese último error, mas sin embargo llegue a un cuello de botella ya que se porque sale pero no se como arreglarlo.

perdón si es mucho texto, pero esta es la única página que deverdad ayuda a la gente a resolver las dudas y más si son tan específicas como estas.

Intente tomar el mismo edit del proyecto el cual usa esto

```
    public function datatables(){
        $id = Auth()->id();
        $table = Datatables::of(User::with('categorias')->where('id','!=',$id)->get());
        $table->addColumn('action', function($row){
            $url = url('usuarios').'/'.$row['id'];
            return view('layouts.buttons_datatables',['id'=>$row['id'],'url'=>$url]);
        })->editColumn('categorias', function($row){
            if (count($row['categorias']) > 0) {
                $message = '';
                foreach ($row['categorias'] as $c) {
                    $message .= view('layouts.categoria_datable',['nombre'=>$c->nombre]);
                }
                return $message;
            }
        })->rawColumns(['action','categorias','permisos']);
        return $table->make(true);
```

mas sin embargo no pude replicarlo y me rendi sinceramente porque no me funcinaba incluso replicandolos y cambiando de nombre todo el nombre de categorias.

Lo unico que mas o menos funciono y supe que funciono porque ya me llama el codigo sql fue este ultimo edit

```
    public function datatables(){
        $table = Datatables::of(Computadores::all());
        $table->addColumn('action', function($row){
            $url = url('computadores').'/'.$row['id'];
            return view('layouts.buttons_datatables',['id'=>$row['id'],'url'=>$url]);
        })->editColumn('idcategoria', function($row){;
             return $row->categoriainv->name;

        })->rawColumns(['action']);
        return $table->make(true);
        
    }
```

Comment: En principio, creo que estas confundiendo el tipo de relación `hasOne` con `belongsTo`. Lo que tendría sentido ahí es que *Una Categoría tenga Muchos Computadores, y Un Computador pertenezca a Una Categoría*. Te sugiero ir paso a paso y primero entender bien de que van las relaciones Eloquent. Te dejo un enlace a la [documentación oficial de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships) donde explica las relaciones

Comment: gracias pa tenias razon, estaba confundiendo las relaciones y las coloque mal a demas de no colocar el caracter que debia de llamar. ya pude solucionarlo

Answer (score 1):

Ya pude solucionarlos, es un tema de relacionar bien lo que vas a llamar para que la tabla te lo traduzca exactamente en mi caso ya tenia todo bien solo me faltaba relacionar bien y llamar el dato que tenia que relacionar, para que quede asi.

Modelo de computador antes (relaciones)

```
public function categoriainv(){
    return $this->hasOne(Categoriainv::class);
}
```

Modelo de computador despues (relaciones)

```
    public function categoriainv(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Categoriainv::class,'idcategoria');
}
```

y el edit del controller sigue siendo el mismo

```
    })->editColumn('idcategoria', function($row){;
            return $row->categoriainv->nombre;
```